# FTS4 matchinfo not working with android room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I've two columns (`name` and `description`) in FTS virtual table and I want to prioritize the `name` column in FTS using `matchinfo` function, but with room in android I'm getting following error:

> Error retrieving data from table.: unable to use function matchinfo in the requested context (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Here is my Query:

```kotlin
@Query("""select workout_cache.id, workout_cache.met, workout_cache.name, workout_cache.workoutDescription, matchinfo(workout_cache_fts, 'pcs') as mi
from workout_cache join workout_cache_fts on workout_cache.id = workout_cache_fts.id 
where workout_cache_fts match :text group by workout_cache.id""")
abstract suspend fun query(text: String): List<WorkoutCacheEntityWithMatchInfo>
```

My `WorkoutCacheEntityWithMatchInfo` class

```kotlin
class WorkoutCacheEntityWithMatchInfo(
    @Embedded
    val workout: WorkoutCacheEntity,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mi")
    val matchInfo: ByteArray
)
```

> UPDATE: It's working fine when I don't use join clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's silly. I just removed the `group by` clause and it worked.

Here updated Dao:

```kotlin
@Query("""select workout_cache.id, workout_cache.met, workout_cache.name, workout_cache.workoutDescription, matchinfo(workout_cache_fts, 'pcs') as mi
from workout_cache join workout_cache_fts on workout_cache.id = workout_cache_fts.id 
where workout_cache_fts match :text""")
abstract suspend fun query(text: String): List<WorkoutCacheEntityWithMatchInfo>
```

Comment: This worked for me too on iOS using Swift.SqlLite. Depending on the match parameter the query worked with the `group by` clause, which is strange. - Any ideas as to why this worked?